# For loop - "Error: Expected a declaration"

Tags: c++, for-loop, multidimensional-array, visual-studio-2013, console

As part of a text-based Battle Ship game, I'm trying to make a simple grid/board appear in the console. Unfortunately I'm having errors just making the grid. The grid is represented by a 2D array, -I'm using a for loop to initially set each element of the grid to "EMPTY". **When I try to get the code running, however, I get an error saying "Expected a declaration" and "syntax error : ')' ". What am I doing wrong?** Here's the portion of code in question:

```
enum GridContent {SHIP, HIT, MISS, EMPTY};

const int GRID_SIZE = 10;

GridContent board[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE];

// Intellisense error on "for": "Expected a declaration."
for (int y = 0; y < GRID_SIZE; y++)
/* Errors for above line: "Missing ';' before '++', '<', '{', and ')'",
"Syntax error: ')'", "Syntax error: 'for'", "'int y' : redefinition"" */
{ // "Missing ';' before '{'"
    for (int x = 0; x < GRID_SIZE; x++)
        board[y][x] = EMPTY;
}
```

Comment: you declare a `board` but then you are trying to assign values to a `grid`. Also it is not clear what is your `Grid`

Comment: moreover you loop over `x` and `y` but then you are trying to access (most likely) invalid indices `GRID_SIZE` in an array where the last index is `GRID_SIZE-1`

Comment: Sorry about my atrocious code! I've edited it now, though I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you mean

```
for (int x = 0; x < GRID_SIZE; x++)
    board[y][x] = EMPTY;
```

instead of

```
for (int x = 0; x < GRID_SIZE; x++)
    grid[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE] = EMPTY;
```

In your code snippet `grid` is an undeclared identifier and .using value `GRID_SIZE` as an index is wrong because the corresponding element will be beyond the array.

Also from your code snippet it is not clear whether the array has to be defined like

```
Grid board[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE];
```

or like

```
GridContent board[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE];
```

Comment: Wow, sorry that my code is a mess. I've edited it so that it makes more sense now. I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @Warran Penner The updated code if you compile it as a C++ code does not contain any error.

Comment: Very strange. I'm trying to run it in Visual Studio 2013 for Desktop, and I'm getting loads of errors. I've updated the snippet again to show what I'm getting. And thanks for your time.

Comment: @Warran Penner Check whether the program file extension is .c instead of .cpp. It might be that you compile your program as a C program.

Comment: It is a .cpp file. I tried it in Code::Blocks, and got "error: expected unqualified-id before ‘for’". Looked it up and it seems I can't use "for" outside of a function. Added a function to fill the grid spaces, and it worked. Is this actually necessary? I'm wondering why it worked for you.

Comment: @Warran Penner Outside functions in namespaces (in your case it seems you used the global name space) you may place only declarations.

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace Grid with GridContent I think in the line
       Grid board[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE];

Answer (score 0):

the array name is board and Grid is the some type.
1. So i side for loop you should used board instead of grid.
2. Your arrays is is GRID_SIZE and when you access you have used that variable which means arrayIndexOutOfBound

Answer (score 0):

Related to Vlad from Moscow's comment about namespaces:
I've had a similar issue and it was because I hadn't included my code with a main block.

ie. The following gets all the errors mentioned:

```
for (int y = 0; y < GRID_SIZE; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < GRID_SIZE; x++)
        board[y][x] = EMPTY;
}
```

But this works fine:

```
int main()
{
    for (int y = 0; y < GRID_SIZE; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < GRID_SIZE; x++)
            board[y][x] = EMPTY;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have to declare the for loop inside a function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Comment: Hm. This may be correct. The code in the question being defined outside a function code might trigger these intellisense error messages. Unfortunately, The OP is no longer around, and we won't know for sure 8 years later.